# ScrollView will not scroll correctly

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

My scroll view will bounce but it will not scroll.

Here is my code snippet:

```
- (void)populateStampList {

    // create a mutable array to populate

    imageNames = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *mImageNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    // List of images

    NSString *img1 = @"moustache";
    NSString *img2 = @"whitem";
    NSString *img3 = @"blackm";
    NSString *img4 = @"monacle";
    NSString *img5 = @"tophat";


    // add images to mutable array

    [mImageNames addObject:img1];
    [mImageNames addObject:img2];
    [mImageNames addObject:img3];
    [mImageNames addObject:img4];
    [mImageNames addObject:img5];


    // set mutable array to array;

    imageNames = mImageNames;
    CGFloat contentSizeWidth = 0.0;
    CGSize newSize = _scrollViewOutlet.frame.size;


    for(int i = 0; i < [imageNames count]; i++){

        NSData *archivedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:_firstImage];
        UIButton *button = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: archivedData];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(badgePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        button.tag = i+1;

        CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(_firstImage.frame.origin.x, _firstImage.frame.origin.y, _firstImage.frame.size.width, _firstImage.frame.size.height);
        newFrame.size.width = _firstImage.frame.size.width;
        newFrame.size.height = _firstImage.frame.size.height;
        newFrame.origin.x += (20+_firstImage.frame.size.width) * i;
        newFrame.origin.y =  _firstImage.frame.origin.y ;
        [button setFrame:newFrame];
         contentSizeWidth = (20+button.frame.size.width) * i;

        NSLog(@"button frame size: %f", _firstImage.frame.size.width);

        NSString *imageName = [[imageNames objectAtIndex:i] stringByAppendingString:@".png"];;

        NSString *documentsDirectory = [utils getDocumentsDirectoryPath];

        //UIImage *image = [utils loadImage:imageName ofType:@"png" inDirectory:documentsDirectory];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName
                          ];        [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [[button imageView] setContentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        [button setAlpha:1.0f];
        [[button imageView] setImage:image];

        [_scrollViewOutlet addSubview:button];
        NSLog(@"scrollViewFrame size: %f", _scrollViewOutlet.frame.size.width);
        NSLog(@"scrollViewFrame size: %f", _scrollViewOutlet.frame.size.height);

        newSize.width = contentSizeWidth+400;
        [_scrollViewOutlet setScrollEnabled:YES];
        [_scrollViewOutlet setContentSize:newSize];
        NSLog(@"scrollviewOutlet Content Width: %f", _scrollViewOutlet.contentSize.width);
        NSLog(@"scrollviewOutlet Content Height: %f", _scrollViewOutlet.contentSize.height);


    }


}
```

Here is my NSLogs:

```
2013-08-08 18:28:39.856 xxxx[4647:907] scrollViewFrame size: 320.000000
2013-08-08 18:28:39.857 xxxx[4647:907] scrollViewFrame size: 86.000000
2013-08-08 18:28:39.858 xxxx[4647:907] scrollviewOutlet Content Width: 768.000000
2013-08-08 18:28:39.859 xxxx[4647:907] scrollviewOutlet Content Height: 86.000000
```

Comment: What do you mean it will bounce but not scroll?

Comment: so... i can hold my finger down on it and drag it but it bounces at the edge of the scrollview frame but does not allow me to drag it to the end of the scrollview content size. Does that make sense?

Comment: Actually I assign a the array to a non mutable array so I can add objects then back. What is confusing about that? Why did you even bother to comment if you are just going to talk about my simple code being confusing.

Comment: Anyway.... it was an auto-layout tick box problem that caused this not my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue. It was an autolayout tick box that needed unticking in the view.